# How to Adding Movie Clip to stage in certain frame (with whole it's event) with source?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

it's my character class , i want the character movie clips which references to this class can be added to stage in certain frame. So when i clicked button start ,it'll adding the character's movieclip . I'd really appreciate if anyone can help me ....

```
package com.ply 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

import flash.ui.Keyboard;

public class Heli extends MovieClip
{
    //Settings
    public var xAcceleration:Number = 0;
    public var yAcceleration:Number = 0;
    private var xSpeed:Number = 0;
    private var ySpeed:Number = 0;

    private var up:Boolean = false;
    private var down:Boolean = false;
    private var left:Boolean = false;
    private var right:Boolean = false;

    private var bullets:Array;
    private var missiles:Array;


    public function Heli()
    {
        init();
    }

    private function init():void
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, runGame);           
    }

    private function runGame(event:Event):void
    {
        xSpeed += xAcceleration ;       //increase the speed by the acceleration
        ySpeed += yAcceleration ;       //increase the speed by the acceleration

        xSpeed *= 0.95;                 //apply friction
        ySpeed *= 0.95;                 //so the speed lowers after time

        if(Math.abs(xSpeed) < 0.02)     //if the speed is really low
        {
            xSpeed = 0;                 //set it to 0
                                //Otherwise I'd go very small but never really 0
        }
        if(Math.abs(ySpeed) < 0.02)     //same for the y speed
        {
            ySpeed = 0;
        }

        xSpeed = Math.max(Math.min(xSpeed, 10), -10);       //dont let the speed get bigger as 10
        ySpeed = Math.max(Math.min(ySpeed, 10), -10);       //and dont let it get lower than -10

        this.x += xSpeed;               //increase the position by the speed
        this.y += ySpeed;               //idem

    }

    /**
     * Keyboard Handlers in main class 
     */

}
```

}

Comment: If you are using frames, why don't you slap the movie clip to the stage at design time?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem here in whole, what are you trying to do, but try this. Change your constructor to this code:

```
public function Heli()
{
   addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}
```

than, change the init() function to `init(e:Event):void`. This will ensure that any initialization done, will be done AFTER you add the MovieClip to the stage. Oh, and on the top of the init() function add this line :
 `removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);`

Than, in the event handler for the button START, create new instance of the class, and added to the stage (or parent container, depending of your game structure).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add character in certain frame, do it. You have two ways:

1. Create instance of character class Heli() use Timer

   `var timer:Timer = new Timer(count_seconds, repeat_parameter)`
   `timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onEventHandler)`
   `timer.start();`

   `function onEventHandler(e:TimerEvent):void`
   `{ create the unstance of Heli here }`
2. You can count frames in EnterFrame handler, and after some values of count create instance of character Heli